# Gmail service events?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I would like to run a processing function whenever a new email arrives in my inbox. I'm looking at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events . I don't see a way to trigger an event when an email arrives. Am I missing something?

Comment: No, you are not. No such trigger for now in apps script.

Comment: There are some workarounds you could use, like labelling new emails and then using the `GmailApp` to poll the number of messages with the label and iterate. It isn't ideal, but can help get what you're looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no email-based triggers in Apps Script, as Serge insas said. As an imperfect workaround, you can run a script every 5 minutes and process the messages that arrived within the latest interval. Here is an example, based on [this post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/95930):

```
function checkEmail() {
  var interval = 5;    //  if the script runs every 5 minutes; change otherwise
  var date = new Date();
  var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
  var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox after:' + timeFrom);
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    threads[i].reply("This is auto-reply for demonstration; you probably want to do something else here.");
  }
}
```