# Google GMAIL add on check attachment on send

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api, gmail-addons

Is there a way to capture the **send event** in the **compose interface** so that checks can be done on the email being sent?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we can read from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46692451/gmail-service-events), "there are no email-based triggers in Apps Script".

On the other hand, client side [InboxSDK library](https://www.inboxsdk.com/docs/#ComposeView) makes it possible to capture ComposeView **sending** and **sent** events. Probably you can use it in custom browser extentions to solve your task.

Comment: Cool, thank you so much for the pointer. Will take a look at it and see how I can use it for my use case.